# Combining elements in jagged 2D arrays into one new jagged 2D array (Deep Copy issue)

Tags: java, arrays

Given two jagged arrays: a & b where a + b will always have the same # of rows:

```
int[][] a = { {1,2}, {4,5,6} };
int[][] b = { {7}, {8,9,0} };
```

how exactly can I manipulate a new jagged array c to return:
`{ {1,2,7}, {4,5,6,8,9,0} }`?

Here's what I have so far:

```
int[][] c = null;    
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
        c = new int[a.length][a[i].length + b[i].length];
}

//rest of my code for assigning the values into the appropriate position works.
```

The trouble arises, as you all can see, that I am performing a deep copy, which, on the second iteration of the for-loop, is setting **ALL** rows to a length of the length of the current row on the step of the iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Flaw in your approach

You are creating a new 2D array object each iteration of your loop. Each time through, you are reassigning `c`, thus throwing out all of your previous work. Additionally, placing a number in both set of brackets at the same time results in **each row having the same length**.

Using your example, the first time through the loop, `c` is assigned to a 2D array with two rows, each of length three. The second time through the loop, you throw out your previous 2D array and create a new one having two rows, each of length six.

But what you need to be doing is creating a new row each time through the loop, not the entire 2D array.

### Solution

First, we create a 2D array called `c` and specify that it has `a.length` rows. We don't put a value in the second bracket, because that would indicate that all of the rows are of the same length. So at this point, `c` does not know about row length. It just knows how many rows it can have. Keep in mind: `c` doesn't actually *have* any rows yet, just a capacity for `a.length` rows.

Next, we must create the rows and assign a length/capacity to them. We set up our loop to run as many times as there are rows. The current row index is denoted by `i`, and therefore, `c[i]` refers to a specific row in the 2D `c` array. We use `new int[]` to create each individual row/array, but inside the brackets, we must specify the length of the current row. For any row `c[i]`, its length is given by the sum of the lengths of `a[i]` and `b[i]`; that is, `a[i].length + b[i].length`.

What we are left with is an array `c` that contains rows/arrays, each with a set length/capacity that matches the sum of the corresponding rows lengths in `a` and `b`.

Keep in mind that `c` still does not contain any integer values, only containers that are of the correct size to hold the values in `a` and `b`. As you mentioned, you already have code to populate your array with values.

```
int[][] c = new int[a.length][];     

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[i] = new int[a[i].length + b[i].length];
}
```

Comment: At least an answer with explanation. Good one.

Answer (score 3):

When initialize Java 2D array, lets consider it as a table; you only have to give the number of rows and in each row of your table can have different number of columns.

Eg. Say we have a 2D array call c defined as follows,

`int[][] c = new int[10][];`

It says you defined c contains 10 of int[] elements. But in order to use it you have to define the number of columns each row has.

Eg. Say we have 3 columns in the second row

`int c[1] = new int[3];`

So in this example you have to add the column values of 2D arrays `a` and `b` to calculate the resultant array which is `c`.

`c[i] = new int[a[i].length + b[i].length];`

This will give you what you expected.

```
    int[][] a = { {1,2}, {4,5,6} };
    int[][] b = { {7}, {8,9,0} };
    int[][] c = new int[a.length][];    
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
            c[i] = new int[a[i].length + b[i].length];
            for (int j=0;j< a[i].length; j++) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
            int length = a[i].length;
            for (int j=0;j< b[i].length; j++) {
                c[i][length+j] = b[i][j];
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `c[i] = new int[a[i].length + b[i].length]`

Comment: I'm going to comment on this one since it's the highest up, but this goes to everyone else who posted pretty much the exact same thing as this post:

why does this work? If I understand this correctly, c[i] is the row, and we're setting the row equal to the right-hand side, but I'm missing how this actual resolves the deep copy issue (you're still deep copying it?).

Comment: Basically, when you make a 2D array, you're creating an array of arrays, so `c[i]` is a 1D array. We're setting each individual row length once, when we actually have the values for that row. Sorry if that isn't a great explanation. What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: I'll explain what is happening in my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[][] c = new int[a.length][];    
for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    c[i] = new int[a[i].length + b[i].length];

    int x = 0;
    for (int num : a[i]) {
        c[i][x] = num;
        x++;
    }
    for (int num : b[i]) {
        c[i][x] = num;
        x++;
    }
}
```

or even simpler...

```
int[][] c = new int[a.length][];    
for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    c[i] = new int[a[i].length + b[i].length];

    System.arraycopy(a[i], 0, c[i], 0, a[i].length);
    System.arraycopy(b[i], 0, c[i], a[i].length, b[i].length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
int[][] c = new int[a.length][];
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){ 
    c[i] = new int [a[i].length + b[i].length];
    int j;
    for(j=0; i < a[i].length; j++){
        c[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
    for(int k=0; i < b[i].length; k++){ 
        c[i][j+k] = b[i][j]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String [] args) {

```
 int[][] a = { {1,2}, {4,5,6} };
 int[][] b = { {7}, {8,9,0} };
 int[][] c = null;    
 for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
         c = new int[a.length][a[i].length + b[i].length];
 }

 for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length+b[i].length; j++) {


    if(j< a[i].length){
        c[i][j]=a[i][j];
    }

    if(j< a[i].length+b[i].length && j>= a[i].length){
        c[i][j]=b[i][j-a[i].length];
    }


    }

 }


 for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length+b[i].length; j++) {
  System.out.print(c[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println();
 }
```

}

This works in my system ...........

Comment: No. It does work, but you are making the same mistake that OP is asking about.  You are wasting memory when you do `c = new int[a.length][a[i].length + b[i].length];` in your loop.  See the other answers for why this is not good.